# ¿Porqué no me manda el dato nombre al activity 2 hasta el 3 pero si lo hace del 1 al 2?

Tags: android-studio

Alguien que me ayude el error esta en variable dt.

```
Activity 1 package com.example.programando; 
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity; 
import android.content.Intent; 
import android.os.Bundle; 
import android.view.View; 
import android.widget.EditText; 
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity { 
    private EditText edt; 
    @Override protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); 
    edt = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.textonombre); 
} 

public void aceptar (View view){ 
    Intent acep = new Intent(this, Main2Activity.class); 
    // edt = getText().toString(); 
    acep.putExtra("dt", edt.getText().toString()); 
    startActivity(acep); 
} 
} 
//Activity 2 package com.example.programando; 
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity; 
import android.content.Intent; 
import android.os.Bundle; 
import android.view.View; 
import android.widget.AdapterView; 
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter; 
import android.widget.ListView; 
import android.widget.TextView; 
public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity { 
  private TextView textoname; 
  private ListView list; 
  private String frases [] = {"El mas bello","El mejor","El malo","El grande","El que mejor programa"}; 
  private TextView tt; 
  @Override protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2); 
  tt = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView); 
  String dt = getIntent().getStringExtra("dt" ); 
  tt.setText("Hola " + dt); 
  list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listvi); 
  ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String> (this,R.layout.listaview2,frases); 
  list.setAdapter(adapter); 
  list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) { 
    Intent ac = new Intent(view.getContext(), Main3Activity.class);
    ac.putExtra("dt",dt); startActivity(ac); 
} 
}); 
// txt.setText("La edad de "+lv.getItemAtPosition(position) + " es "+ edades[position]+" años"); 
} 
} 
//Acitivity 3 package com.example.programando; 
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity; 
import android.content.Intent; 
import android.os.Bundle; 
import android.widget.EditText; 
import android.widget.TextView; 
public class Main3Activity extends AppCompatActivity { 
  private TextView tex; 
  // private EditText tc; 
  @Override protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main3); 
    tex = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.texto3); 
    // // tc = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textonombre); 
    String dt = getIntent().getStringExtra("dt" ); 
    tex.setText("Soy " + dt); 
    // tex.setText("La edad de "+list.getItemAtPosition(position) + " es "+ edades[position]+" años"); 
} 
}
```

---

Answer (score 0):

en tu activity debes tener algo asi

```
Intent i = new Intent(Activity1.this, Activity2.class);
i.putExtra("nombres", "Diego");
startActivity(i);
```

y en tu activity 2 recibes ese valor de la siguiente manera

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String nombres_recibidos = intent.getStringExtra("nombres");
```

y para enviar eso a tu tercer activity debes hacer en el activity 2 el mismo proceso del activity 1

Answer (score 0):

Prueba a sustituir esto:

```
Intent ac = new Intent(view.getContext(), Main3Activity.class);
```

Por esto:

```
Intent ac = new Intent(Main2Activity.this, Main3Activity.class);
```

Comment: Gracias pude recolverlo

Comment: Si esta respuesta resolvio tu duda, recuerda marcala como aceptada @user138149